# Calculating time to next and last events, with unevenly distributed event times

Tags: dplyr, time

I am trying to write a code that will return two separate variables: one for time from a current event to the next event for a specific individual, and one for the time since the last event happened for a specific individual, for each of the events in my data frame.

Right now I have a data frame where each row is an event, and the data frame includes many individuals (with distinct ID markers in the ID.2 column). My events are not evenly distributed through time; sometimes no events happen for many days, and then there are 5+ events within one day. I  have a Datetime column in as.posix format, that comprises my date and time. I have created columns for time to next event (ttne) and time since last event (tspe), but am not sure how to populate the fields! I am a super R beginner so would appreciate any help this wonderful community can give!

My data looks like:

```
    > head(ACss)
    > Date         Datetime          ID.2 month day year tspe
    > 1 2019-05-25 2019-05-25 11:57  139     5  25 2019   NA
    > 2 2019-06-09 2019-06-09 19:42   43     6   9 2019   NA
    > 3 2019-07-05 2019-07-05 20:12  139     7   5 2019   NA
    > 4 2019-07-27 2019-07-27 17:27  152     7  27 2019   NA
    > 5 2019-08-04  2019-08-04 9:13  152     8   4 2019   NA
    > 6 2019-08-04 2019-08-04 16:18  139     8   4 2019   NA
```

I have tried a few different mutate and group functions in DPLYR, with no luck!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtWxR.png)

Comment: Time to next event for row `i` is equivalent to time since previous event for row `i+1` . Do you need both columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fast data.table approach (see data below). Also, however, see my comment above that time to next event for a row is equal to time since prior event for the following rows.

```
setorder(data,ID.2,Datetime)
data[, `:=`(tspe=Datetime - shift(Datetime), ttne = shift(Datetime,-1)-Datetime), by=.(ID.2)][]

                 Datetime  ID.2           tspe           ttne
                   <POSc> <int>     <difftime>     <difftime>
   1: 2019-01-11 22:07:56     1        NA secs 6605737.1 secs
   2: 2019-03-29 10:03:33     1 6605737.1 secs 1597959.3 secs
   3: 2019-04-16 21:56:13     1 1597959.3 secs 5108436.7 secs
   4: 2019-06-15 00:56:49     1 5108436.7 secs  169861.8 secs
   5: 2019-06-17 00:07:51     1  169861.8 secs  547332.5 secs
  ---                                                        
4996: 2019-12-06 12:49:24   200 7668946.3 secs  471838.4 secs
4997: 2019-12-11 23:53:22   200  471838.4 secs  100658.9 secs
4998: 2019-12-13 03:51:01   200  100658.9 secs  402635.4 secs
4999: 2019-12-17 19:41:36   200  402635.4 secs  547332.5 secs
5000: 2019-12-24 03:43:49   200  547332.5 secs        NA secs
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
data %>%
  arrange(ID.2,Datetime) %>% 
  group_by(ID.2) %>%
  mutate(tspe=Datetime - lag(Datetime),
         tsne=lead(Datetime)-Datetime
)
   Datetime             ID.2 tspe           tsne          
   <dttm>              <int> <drtn>         <drtn>        
 1 2019-01-11 22:07:56     1        NA secs 6605737.1 secs
 2 2019-03-29 10:03:33     1 6605737.1 secs 1597959.3 secs
 3 2019-04-16 21:56:13     1 1597959.3 secs 5108436.7 secs
 4 2019-06-15 00:56:49     1 5108436.7 secs  169861.8 secs
 5 2019-06-17 00:07:51     1  169861.8 secs  547332.5 secs
 6 2019-06-23 08:10:04     1  547332.5 secs 2900233.2 secs
 7 2019-07-26 21:47:17     1 2900233.2 secs  981423.8 secs
 8 2019-08-07 06:24:21     1  981423.8 secs  257938.3 secs
 9 2019-08-10 06:03:19     1  257938.3 secs  553623.7 secs
10 2019-08-16 15:50:23     1  553623.7 secs  195026.5 secs
```

Input:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
data = data.table(
  Datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2019-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2019-12-31"), length.out = 5000)
)
data[, ID.2:=sample(1:200, nrow(data), replace=T)]
```

Comment: Hi again Langtang!! Thanks so much for your answer here! I tried to run the dplyr version, and had an error message come up (Warning message:
`...` is not empty.
We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`
These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.) I saw that you put some code under "Input" should i run this code first?

Comment: hmm, did you run on my input data or yours? It seems to run okay on my input data. Can you `dput(head(20))` your data, so can see exactly what the format is?

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm getting this error because I have many more columns in my data frame that what I put here, and some of them have NA's in them? My error message is highlighting NA fields that are in columns not included in this code, so maybe there is an issue there?

Comment: It shouldn't be affected by other columns, at least not in anyway that I can currently see.. the dplyr code simply adds two columns to the dataset ; I do see an extra parentheses in my dplyr code, but it is at the bottom and shouldn't be the problem. I'll remove now

Comment: It looks like there are too many characters for me to add it here as a comment! There are a LOT of columns....

Comment: But when I run the dplyr command this is part of the error message - its highlighting NA's in columns I'm not using here...

Comment: X.3   X.2   X.1     X Data.Source Observer Veh..Mark Date.original Date 
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <fct>       <fct>    <fct>     <fct>         <fct>
 1   924   924  5166   746 2003-2009 … Jay Hon… Y         2005-08-18 1… 2005…
 2  5601  5601  5181   761 2003-2009 … Melanie… Y         2005-08-20 1… 2005…
 3  5602  5602  5182   762 2003-2009 … Melanie… Y         2005-08-20 1… 2005…
 4  2323  2323  5183   763 2003-2009 … Melanie… NA        2005-08-20 1… 2005…
 5  5606  5606  5187   767 2003-2009 … Gustavs… Y         2005-08-21 2… 2005…

Comment: we always dput the data structure in the question not in the comments: one other thing to try, is prefix all the dplyr verbs with `dplyr::` (perhaps you have not loaded the packages or perhaps you have other packages that are masking the verbs..

Comment: That is so helpful, thank you Langtang - I'm very new to all of this! I tried adding "df1 <-  "before the rest of the command and it worked! I think I have some issues/glitches with tibble and for some reason this worked. Now the whole command is: df1 <- df1 %>%
  arrange(ID.2, Datetime) %>% 
  group_by(ID.2) %>%
  mutate(tspe=Datetime - lag(Datetime),
         ttne=lead(Datetime)-Datetime)

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help here! I really appreciate it!